# How do I set the style of an element to the values in a parent style sheet in a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using the [960 Smart Grid](http://dryan.github.io/css-smart-grid/) to design a website. It's a mobile first grid system, and I'm having a bit of trouble. In order for the grid system to work, the padding-left element cannot change or it breaks, except in the default layout when everything is a single column.

I needed to adjust the padding for an element in the mobile view, which screws up the element when it's larger than the single-column view width (so greater than 768 px). I need to change the padding back to what the original smart-grid style sheet says, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm fairly new to this, I don't have the site live at the moment but I can share any code needed. I'm adjusting the padding on a paragraph element, set inside of a div element.

```
<div id="intro" class="columns twelve" class="row">
            <p id="tagline" class="columns eight offset-two">Sample Text.</p>
</div>
```

Essentially, I need to set a 6% padding for the paragraph element in the mobile view. Once it reaches a minimu width of 768 pixels, I need to eliminate the 6% padding because it breaks the offset-two portion of the tag. The offset is achieved in the smart grid style sheet using a padding-left value based upon the screen size. I'd like to switch back to the default padding from the smart grid style sheet for all of the media queries, if possible. You can check out the basic grid documentation on the site I linked to at the beginning of the question.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can set different styles on an element for different screen sizes with @media rules—which measure things like the screen width and set styles for various widths. So when the browser gets to a certain width, you can add/remove the padding as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but it looks like you just need to overwrite the padding for when the browser is less than 768 pixels.

To do this, you just need to add, at the end of your main css (or in a new one, but called after the other one):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .columns.eight.offset-two {
   padding: 6%;
   }
}
```

This means that this style will only be applied **if** the browser is smaller than 768px, and once it gets bigger, it will bring back the 'default' padding for your element. You don't need to specify the padding again for bigger resolutions,l because the second the browser gets past the number, it completely forgets about the media query (it's like it doesn't exist anymore). The only thing you need to keep in mind is, unless you set another smaller media query after this one, it will apply the 6% to all smaller sizes.

It's important that you keep your media queries at the end, because css is read from top to bottom, and the last style read will be the last applied.

Comment: Oh, duh. You're absolutely right. I've been using min-width for all of my media queries, it didn't occur to me that I could simply use the reverse for this one instance. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to tick the answer if it helped you, best of luck!